# Git failed when attempting to retrieving qt5 source code for compiling under Windows

Tags: git, qt

I am trying to build qt5 on windows. I am following the instructions from "[Building Qt 5 from Git](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)".

However, I am not even able retrieve the soure code successfully.
The initial command “`git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5`” completed successfully.
But the next command “perl init-repository” failed with the following error information:

```
 + git submodule init 0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
 AllocationBase 0×0, BaseAddress 0×68560000, RegionSize 0×170000, State 0×10000
 c:\program files (x86)\git\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn’t reserve space for cygwin’s h
 eap, Win32 error 0
 git submodule init exited with status 256 at init-repository line 268. Qt::InitRepository::exe(‘Qt::InitRepository=HASH ’, ‘git’, ‘sub
 module’, ‘init’) called at init-repository line 373 Qt::InitRepository::git_submodule_init(‘Qt::Init Repository=HASH’) called at init-repository line 569 Qt::InitRepository::run(‘Qt::InitRepository=HASH ’) called at i
 nit-repository line 590
```

I am using msysgit (Git for Windows) 1.8.1.2, Active Perl 5.16.3 and Python 3.3.0.

Comment: I've reproduced this just now with Git for Windows 2.32.0.windows.2 (64-bit), Python 3.9.0, and Active Perl v5.26.3, whilst trying to clone Qt 5.12.4

Gotta love that 8 year bump for a fix

Answer (score 0):

Check if the dll fix recommended in [issue 133](https://web.archive.org/web/20100913104703/http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=133) works:

> Seems it is not fixed, I ran into this issue today. The dll fix did work though.
>
> I'm using Git-1.7.8-preview20111206.

The fix is for downloading [msys-1.0.dll](http://repo.or.cz/w/msysgit.git?a=blob_plain;f=bin/msys-1.0.dll;hb=msys) ([initially available here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121020075556/http://www.madwizard.org/electronics/articles/winavrvista)), and replace it in `c:\yourPath\Git\bin`.

---

[coolhandle01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535386/coolhandle01) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607905/git-failed-when-attempting-to-retrieving-qt5-source-code-for-compiling-under-win/15609251#comment121675567_15609251):

> I reported this to git-for-windows ([issue 3369](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3369)), but I don't think it's their fault really: **swapping out `perl init-repository` for `git submodule update --init` got me up and running**: I figure the `git` CLI has changed and Qt5 hasn't kept up (why would they, I guess? Qt 6 is out after all).

Comment: I've just seen this with Git for Windows 2.32.0.windows. FYI, all your links are dead or forbidden

Comment: @coolhandle01 Strange: what is your Windows OS version? I have restored link 1 and 3 in the answer.

Comment: I'm using 21H1 (19043.1165)

I [reported this to git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3369), but I don't think it's their fault really: swapping out `perl init-repository` for `git submodule update --init` got me up and running: I figure the git CLI has changed and Qt5 hasn't kept up (why would they, I guess? Qt 6 is out after all)

Thanks for restoring the links, I'll take a gander

Comment: @coolhandle01 Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.